# How to place an entire c++ namespace at a particular memory location?

Tags: c++, namespaces, memory-address

How to place a c++ namespace at a particular memory location for an embedded setup? I tried using
**attribute**((section("sectionName"))) but it is being ignored by the compiler.

Comment: C++ does not provide a mechanism to locating code.  You'll need to use extensions provided by your compiler or linker.  (For example, on my old platform I could give my linker a linker map for ordering functions so closely associated functions could be near each other in memory.  Seems that's similar to what you want with `attribute((section("sectionName")))`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "an entire c++ namespace"? A namespace can contain code, global variables, global constants... Those are usually linked t different parts of memory, especially in embedded environments. Please clarify by providing details on the effect you are hoping for.

Comment: my namespace contain  constant variables and few constant arrays. Since all of them belong to same namespace, flash addresses alloted to them are contiguous.  I want the starting address  i.e the address of  the first member of namespace to be programmable in code.

Comment: Namespaces don't really organize things in memory. They only organize the names of things. You'll have to ask to put all the things *in* the namespace at the particular location.

Comment: I highly recommend studying the compiler's documentation.  For example, the IAR compiler allows variables placed in segments using the `@ segment-name` specifier (which is an extension to the C language).  Your compiler may have different techniques for placing code vs variables.  Also read up on the linker's documentation/manual as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use linker scripts to map different program sections to different memory regions, etc.. It would give you some flexibility however please note that it is not guaranteed that a **namespace** would be a single section.

For you to know static variables are placed in different section than global variables and same for automatic variables (on a stack) etc...

**Update:**

It does not matter if variables are in one file or many because the placement of the symbols happen at the other stage.

Constant variable is a global (I assume you are talking about globals) and it will go to `.rodata` (read only data) because it is constant.

Consider following example:

```
➜  ~ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const int varGlobal = 0;
static int varStatic;
int varNonconst = 1;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

And lets peek onto the binary:

```
➜  ~ objdump -t main | rg var
0000000000002008 l     O .rodata        0000000000000004              _ZL9varGlobal
0000000000004138 l     O .bss   0000000000000004              _ZL9varStatic
00000000000012bb l     F .text  0000000000000019              _GLOBAL__sub_I_varNonconst
0000000000004010 g     O .data  0000000000000004              varNonconst
```

From there you see where each one of them has ended up.

Comment: what if all members of a namespace are constant variables? Isn't it guaranteed that they will occupy contiguous memory? Moreover, this namespace is defined as a single module i.e a file containing only the namespace.

Comment: @Mehreen constant variables (when compiled with optimizations on) are often part of the generated code at the place where they are used and not located at a distinct memory location.

Comment: Code, variable and data placement is compiler & linker dependent.  May also be platform or OS dependent as well.  For example, a compiler or linker may decide to place global and static variables in the same segment.  Constants may be placed in a read-only segment or the code segment.

Comment: Local variables may be placed in the stack, they may use registers, or they could be placed into another memory segment.  There is no storage requirements mandated by the C++ standard (lifetimes, yes, but not storage locations). There is one processor that has a separate memory segment for stack, that can also be treated as RAM (byte addressable).